# Set label above discrete steps seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to SeekBar with descrete value ( I set that ) but how to set labels above with that discrete values ? I tried with label but it is not aligned. Is there any default value to do this ?

Comment: What have you tried? please provide some code. and your question is not yet clear. You need to show the seek-progress in label when use changes the seekbar thumb position or something else?

Comment: i think it's possible to create custom layout seekbar back image.